# Using @Secured on Token based authorization for REST endpoints

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

i've been trying to do an Token (JWT) based Authentication and Authorization for my Spring Application. Of course via Spring Security. I've been able to do the authentication part via Filters. However, I can't seem to authorize the request based on the JWT token sent on HTTP Request. See below for my sample code.

**TestRest.java (RestController)**

```
@RestController
public class TestRest {

    @GetMapping(value="/protected")
    @Secured("ROLE_USER")
    public @ResponseBody String protectedMethod () {
        logger.info("Entering Proceted Method! is {}" , SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities());
        return "I am Protected!";
    }
}
```

**JwtAuthTokenFilter.java (Token Filter)**

```
@Component
public class JwtAuthTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter{
... some code ...

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        logger.info("Firing JWT Token Filter.");

        String authHeader = request.getHeader(this.prop.getHeader());
        String authToken = null;
        String username = null;
        Date expiry = null; 
        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = null;;
        //if (requestHeader != null && requestHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
        if (authHeader != null && authHeader.startsWith(bearer)) {
            authToken = authHeader.substring(bearer.length());

            try {
                logger.info("Token: {}",authToken);
                username = jwtUtil.getUsernameFromToken(authToken);
                authorities = AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList(jwtUtil.getAudienceFromToken(authToken));
                logger.info("Username: {}", username);
                logger.info("Roles: {}", authorities);
                logger.info("Issue At: {}", jwtUtil.getIssuedAtDateFromToken(authToken));
                logger.info("Expiration: {}", jwtUtil.getExpirationDateFromToken(authToken));

            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                logger.error("Error Occurred {}", e);
            } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
                logger.warn("Token Expired! {}", e);
            }

            if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
                logger.info("authorizingi user!!!");

                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, null, authorities);
                auth.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                logger.info("{} is authorized", username);
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
            }

        }else {
            logger.info("No header, ignoring");
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        logger.info("Closing JWT TOken Filter.");
    }
... some code ...
}
```

The above filter is loosely based on a guide i've read regarding authenticating JWT Tokens. Credits to the guy. Currently, i'am doing the `@Secured` java configuration to secure all my REST-API endpoints. I won't do the setting of User Roles in the Web Configuration due to the maintainability part wherein you have to define in the `antMatchers`. So i will implement the `@Secured` on every REST-API endpoints. However, i can't seem to make the user (in JWT token) authorized in all my REST-API endpoints.

How do you set the authorization so that `@Secured` can recognize it?

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/197973/create-annotation-to-validate-jwt-in-spring-controller-instead-of-filter (Not exactly what you are asking, could be useful)

Comment: ohh i see, thanks i got the main idea, but as much as possible im gonna use whats in spring. Last resort is to create something like what you referred to me. I am not yet familiar with all the functionality in spring. Maybe someone here who has years of experience dealing with spring can help. Thanks!